# Why does Django not find the admin/base_site.html file when I dockerize the app?

Tags: python, django, docker

I've downloaded this Django app and put it in a docker container.

However, I get the error "admin/base_site.html" not found.

If I open a shell on the container and do `find /|grep base_site` I see the file is correctly installed in `/usr/local/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html`

The code I'm referring to can be found in https://github.com/DDecoene/bots

Could you be so kind and take a look? I've busted my head over this for a day and can't figure it out, nor find anything on Google that is even remotely related.

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look like your docker file  has a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` defined, how are you running it?

Comment: The docker-compose.yml file has a command in it. I use `docker-compose up` to start the container